# How to implement json data in a loop? (html & javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, json

I got some data from my json file that I implement in my html. The data is displayed correctly. My problem is that I would like to put them in a loop to duplicate the html, and that the data json adapt.

Let me explain more. I have several cards representing different schools. Inside each one has the same data, but this one must adapt according to the school.

With my current code, the loop is formed but each card overwrites the previous one. So, only the eighth is displayed.

If anyone can help me, it would be great. Ideally, I would not like to use ajax. Thank you so much !

Extract of my json file :

```
{
    "1": {
        "validatorID": "1",
        "address": "0x8b...",
        "name": "Name test",
        "intentDeclaration": "Lorem ipsum",
        "KYBHash": "104c99...",
        "ID": "1",
        "logo": "https://gallery.mailchimp.com/06805e35e34db6974972f20f6/files/ed545cd7-82e6-49a8-bf0c-73f8220e4478/chain_accelerator.svg",
        "country": "fr",
        "continent": "eu"
    },
     "2": {
        "validatorID": "2",
        "address": "0x8b2...",
        "name": "Name test2",
        "intentDeclaration": "Lorem ipsum2",
        "KYBHash": "104c992...",
        "ID": "2",
        "logo": "https://gallery.mailchimp.com/06805e35e34db6974972f20f6/files/ed545cd7-82e6-49a8-bf0c-73f8220e4478/chain_accelerator.svg",
        "country": "fr",
        "continent": "eu"
    }
```

Extract of my Js file

```
$.getJSON('js/issuers.json', function(donnees) {
  for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {

  $(".testjson").html(
    "<div class='row'>"+
    "<div class=\"one-card col-lg-3 col-md-6 wow fadeInUp\">"+
        "<div class=\"card\">"+
    "<div class=\"card-container-img\">"+
      "<img src=\""+donnees[i].logo+"\"+ class=\"card-img-top\" alt=\""+donnees[i].name+"\">"+
    "</div>"+
       "<div class=\"card-body\">"+
    "<h2 class=\"issuer-name\">"+donnees[i].name+"</h2>"+
       "<p class=\"issuer-important\"><span class=\"country\">"+donnees[i].country+"</span> <span class=\"continent\">"+donnees[i].continent+"</span></p>"+
      "<p class=\"issuer-number\">"+donnees[i].address+"</p>"+
    "<p class=\"declaration\">"+
      "<i class=\"icon-quote-start quote\"></i>"+
       donnees[i].intentDeclaration+
        "<i class=\"icon-quote quote\"></i>"+
    "</p>"+

                       [...]
  "</div>"+
"</div>"+
"</div>"
    ); }
});
```

Extract of my HTML file :

```
<div class="testjson"></div>
```

Comment: Thats because you override the html element. You must create for each entry in the json its own html container/element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your json data is overwrite one by one.
It means your write first value, second value ... and last value.
So you have to join all values.

```
$.getJSON('js/issuers.json', function(donnees) {
  let jsonData = "";
  for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {

    jsonData +=
    "<div class='row'>"+
    "<div class=\"one-card col-lg-3 col-md-6 wow fadeInUp\">"+
        "<div class=\"card\">"+
    "<div class=\"card-container-img\">"+
      "<img src=\""+donnees[i].logo+"\"+ class=\"card-img-top\" alt=\""+donnees[i].name+"\">"+
    "</div>"+
       "<div class=\"card-body\">"+
    "<h2 class=\"issuer-name\">"+donnees[i].name+"</h2>"+
       "<p class=\"issuer-important\"><span class=\"country\">"+donnees[i].country+"</span> <span class=\"continent\">"+donnees[i].continent+"</span></p>"+
      "<p class=\"issuer-number\">"+donnees[i].address+"</p>"+
    "<p class=\"declaration\">"+
      "<i class=\"icon-quote-start quote\"></i>"+
       donnees[i].intentDeclaration+
        "<i class=\"icon-quote quote\"></i>"+
    "</p>"+

                       [...]
  "</div>"+
"</div>"+
"</div>";
    }
   $(".testjson").html(jsonData);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try using append like explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append).**

```
$.getJSON('js/issuers.json', function(donnees) {
  for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {

  $(".testjson").append(
    "<div class='row'>"+
    "<div class=\"one-card col-lg-3 col-md-6 wow fadeInUp\">"+
        "<div class=\"card\">"+
    "<div class=\"card-container-img\">"+
      "<img src=\""+donnees[i].logo+"\"+ class=\"card-img-top\" alt=\""+donnees[i].name+"\">"+
    "</div>"+
       "<div class=\"card-body\">"+
    "<h2 class=\"issuer-name\">"+donnees[i].name+"</h2>"+
       "<p class=\"issuer-important\"><span class=\"country\">"+donnees[i].country+"</span> <span class=\"continent\">"+donnees[i].continent+"</span></p>"+
      "<p class=\"issuer-number\">"+donnees[i].address+"</p>"+
    "<p class=\"declaration\">"+
      "<i class=\"icon-quote-start quote\"></i>"+
       donnees[i].intentDeclaration+
        "<i class=\"icon-quote quote\"></i>"+
    "</p>"+

                       [...]
  "</div>"+
"</div>"+
"</div>"
    ); }
});
```

Also to make the code more readable you might want to try [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which lets you write the whole string without appending and escaping quotes like this `\"`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It was not working whith me, but the MobDevelop's answer working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery ($.each) to iterate over json (object). And you can try something like this:

Html

```
<div class="testjson"></div>
```

Js:

```
$.getJSON('js/issuers.json', function(response) {

    $.each(response, funtion(key, value){
       $(".testjson").append(
       "<div class='row'>"+
        "<div class=\"one-card col-lg-3 col-md-6 wow fadeInUp\">"+
        "<div class=\"card\">"+
           "<div class=\"card-container-img\">"+
          "<img src=\""+ value.logo+"\"+ class=\"card-img-top\" alt=\""+value.name+"\">"+
           "</div>"+
         "<div class=\"card-body\">"+
        "<h2 class=\"issuer-name\">"+value.name+"</h2>"+
          "<p class=\"issuer-important\"><span class=\"country\">"+value.country+" 
         </span> <span class=\"continent\">"+value.continent+"</span></p>"+
         "<p class=\"issuer-number\">"+value.address+"</p>"+
        "<p class=\"declaration\">"+
         "<i class=\"icon-quote-start quote\"></i>"+
       value.intentDeclaration+
        "<i class=\"icon-quote quote\"></i>"+
    "</p>"+

                       [...]
     "</div>"+
   "</div>"+
   "</div>");
  });
 });
```

Comment: I'm glad that is working for you! But why are hard-coding the iteration to iterate over 9th times only?

Answer (score -1):

in each iteration in your loop you overwrite your `.testjson` html with new data, all you need to do is to append it to it, would be something like :
`$('.testjson').html($('.testjson).html() + ... )`

Comment: Use `.append()` - better than building like this

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The MobDevelop's method working ;)